# Decoupling script from requirejs / Preventing adBlocker from halting download

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I built a helper that loads iframes dynamically which contain advertisements from double click. The problem is, if I call the helper inside of require.js and with adBlock ON, Backbone is blocked from loading. I tried moving it to a self executing function but it requires underscore and jquery.

helper:

```
(define('helpers/advertisements', [
  'jquery',
  'lodash'
], )function($, _) {

  'use strict';

  var Advertisement = {
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('init');
    }
  }
 return Advertisement;

});
```

AppLayout:

```
'use strict';

define('master/views/AppLayout', [
  'backbone',
  'marionette',
  'helpers/advertisements'
], function(Backbone, Marionette, AdHelper) {

  // Define the application layout specific regions
  return Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

    onRender: function() {
      AdHelper.initialize();
    }

  });

});
```

Here is how I decoupled it:

html: `<script src="helpers/advertisments.js"></script>`

helper:

```
(function($, _) {

      'use strict';

  var Advertisement = {
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('init');
    }
  }

 Advertisement.initialize()

})($, _);
```

**1.) What would be the best way for me to decouple a helper function?**

**2.) Or would it be better to use a deferred/promise within require?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try requiring it inline, in an an "after initialize" callback. Something like

```
MyApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
  require('helpers/advertisements', function(AdHelper){
    AdHelper.initialize();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a great way to make sure my calls occurred after the app was initialized. The second step I had to use was renaming my filed from advertisements since adblocker seems to look for those calls.